# Best way to transition a div off the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

I want to hide my menu and slide it off the screen.. the css is inline react but it's still the same thing. How can I make it so when the div slides off the screen it disapears.. right now I just slide it off the screen but because it never changes display to 'none' it just sits there.

```
slideFromBelow: {
            displayed: {
                display: 'block',
                top: 0,
                transition: "top 500ms ease-in-out 0s"
            },
            hidden: {
                display: 'block',
                top: "100%",
                transition: "top 500ms ease-in-out 0s"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you not change the display to `none`?

Comment: If not, you could add an opacity to hidden, so something like this: `opacity: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideFromBelow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.container:hover .slideFromBelow{
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slideFromBelow">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can make it invisible and put it in the back

```
visibility: hidden;
z-index: -1;
```